# Ошибка типа значения в протофайле при «ручном» запуске

Tags: python, типы-данных, type-error

Осуществляю запуск некоторого скрипта, при этом возникает следующая ошибка:

> TypeError: 62 has type < type 'int' >, but expected one of: ( < type
>   'str' >, < type 'unicode' >)

Природа ошибки непонятна. Запуская все это посредством automake все работает. Запуская из терминала — выдает ошибку.  При этом в прото-файле, поле, запрашиваемое для значения 62, `required uint32`. Где может быть проблема? Прикладываю полный скрин вывода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть вот такая функция

```
def get_patch_info(self):
        if self.mode == "manual":
            pi = patch_symbol.resolve(self.bf_old.elf, self.bf_new.elf)
        elif self.mode == "auto":
            raise Exception("Not implemented")
        else:
            print "Unknown patch mode: \"%s\"" % self.mode

        if not pi.func_jumps:
            raise Exception("No functions to patch")

        for fj in pi.func_jumps:
            if fj.func_size < MIN_FUNC_SIZE:
                raise Exception("Function '%s' size less than minimal: %d < %d" %
                            fj.name, fj.func_size, MIN_FUNC_SIZE)

        print "\n*************************************************"
        print "***************** Patch info ********************"
        print "*************************************************\n"

        pi.old_bid = get_build_id(self.bf_old.elf)
        pi.new_bid = get_build_id(self.bf_new.elf)

        pi.new_arch_type = ENUM_E_MACHINE[self.bf_new.elf.header.e_machine]


        print "Header:"
        print "  Target BuildId: %s" % pi.old_bid
        print "  Patch BuildId : %s" % pi.new_bid
        print "  Architecture on which patch is built : %u" % pi.new_arch_type

        if self.patchfile:
            pi.new_path = self.bf_new.filename
            print "  Patch path    : %s" % pi.new_path

        self.pi = pi
```

Есть вот такой протофайл:

```
import "funcjump.proto";
import "markedsym.proto";
import "staticsym.proto";

message BinPatch {
    required string     old_bid     = 1;
    required string     new_bid     = 2;
    optional string     new_path    = 3;
    repeated FuncJump   func_jumps  = 4;
    repeated MarkedSym  manual_symbols  = 5;
    repeated StaticSym  static_symbols  = 6;
    repeated MarkedSym  global_symbols  = 7;
    required uint32     new_arch_type   = 8;
}
```

Соотвветсвенно все крашится на строке:

```
pi.new_arch_type = ENUM_E_MACHINE[self.bf_new.elf.header.e_machine]
```

Если переписать `required uint32 new_arch_type = 8;` на `required string new_arch_type = 8;`, в функции `pi.new_arch_type = ENUM_E_MACHINE[self.bf_new.elf.header.e_machine]` заменить на `pi.new_arch_type = self.bf_new.elf.header.e_machine`, то все работает верно. Но это работа со строками. Мне нужно передать это через числа. При запуске из терминала - ошибка выше.

Comment: _Проблема может быть в некоторой ошибке_. А если серьёзно, по приведённому описанию понять что бы то ни было невозможно. Методом антинаучного тыка мне удалось найти репозиторий, в котором есть код, который вы, вероятно, запускаете (https://github.com/greylord1996/Project), но я сомневаюсь, что кто-то захочет копаться в нём. Попробуйте создать [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @fori1ton Добавил код из проекта, надеюсь, поможет понять мою проблему.

Comment: Вроде тут по трейсбеку видно в чем ошибка... только трейсбек скриншотом, не надо так. И там в репозитории серьезно .zip файл с кодом и папкой .git лежит?..

Answer (score 1):

> Запуская все это посредством automake все работает. Запуская из терминала — выдает ошибку.

Вероятно при запуске из терминала забыли скомпилировать .proto-файл, а в скомпилированной ранее версии осталось поле типа string. А при запуске через automake сборка производится где-то в другом месте.